# Como hacer consulta de una tabla de sqlserver con (numeric) a c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo un problema y es que estoy intentando hacer una consulta de c# a sqlserver pero me sale el siguiente error

> System.InvalidCastException: 'No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo
>   'System.Decimal' al tipo 'System.String'

Y se que el error viene al parecer de que tengo una columna denominada "Edad" de tipo numeric y al hacer la consulta en c# tomandola como String me da el error, la gran pregunta seria, Como podria llamarla correctamente para que pueda ejecutarse correctamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
        //Consulta 
    public static List<Estudiante> BuscarEstudiante(String pcedula)
    {
        List<Estudiante> Lista = new List<Estudiante>();
        using (SqlConnection conexion = BDcomun.ObtenerCOnexion())
        {
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(string.Format(                         //Cambie el 1 por el 0
                "Select nombre, cedula, correo, edad from Estudiante where cedula like '%{0}%'", pcedula), conexion);
            SqlDataReader reader = comando.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Estudiante pEstudiante = new Estudiante();
                pEstudiante.nombre = reader.GetString(0);
                pEstudiante.cedula = reader.GetString(1);
                pEstudiante.correo = reader.GetString(2);
                pEstudiante.edad   = reader.GetString(3);

                Lista.Add(pEstudiante);
            }
            conexion.Close();
            return Lista;
            //Fin consulta
```

El error creo que proviene justo de

> pEstudiante.edad = reader.**GetString**(3);

Comment: ¿Cómo declaraste el atributo edad de la clase estudiante? ¿Que tipo de dato es?

Comment: En sql-server el tipo de dato de (edad) es numeric(10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas convertir el tipo de dato a tipo `string` ya que `reader` devuelve un tipo [System.Decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdecimal(v=vs.110).aspx), si tu clase `Estudiante` acepta strings basta con una conversion simple utilizando:

```
pEstudiante.edad = reader.GetDecimal(3).ToString();
```

Comment: Si, era esto muchisimas gracias